# Count in Eloquent with distinct?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

the following query:

```
Sheep::whereIn('foobar_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])->groupBy('foobar_id')->count();
```

Also instead of using `groupBy` I tried `distinct('foobar_id')` with no effect.
How can I get a result of the counts where doubles of the `foobar_id` are skipped?
Using Postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sheep::query()
   ->whereIn('foobar_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
   ->distinct()
   ->count('foobar_id');
```